# WebApi C# - Strange Application User Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Has anyone ever came across this issue where a receiving a JSON request causes an error with the code being 500 referring to serializing the claims

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
    // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    // Add custom user claims here
    return userIdentity;
}
```

I've used this many times and never encountered such an error.

This is the error message I am receiving:

> Error getting value from 'Claims' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser_1D901F7450B712718356A9F1E1E965E3B124374C4686CB161B4EE02591FE03F5'

Comment: It seems serialization issue.

Comment: Are you storing any custom claims?

Comment: Arshad, yes I am aware of this but I've never encountered this issue before hence the post on here. I am not storing any custom claims Brendan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with Lazy Loading. Placing the following in my constructor has fixed my issue.

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I encountered this for the first time today and your advice solved it... but it entices the question as to ...why?

Comment: Mark, I'm unsure as to why I've used Entity Framework many times and this issue had never popped up before...